# How do Ocean's 13 rip Bank of 500 million dollars in one night?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-thirteen

In the movie Ocean's 13, they rig every game in the casino in order for Bank to lose as much as possible. But once everyone is on a winning streak, Danny gives the green light to start the "earthquake", forcing Bank to go to the room where the Greco is stored and forcing it to reboot due to the magnetron in his cell phone. But in the 3 minute window when the system is dowm, everyone wins big but no one ever cashes out! Only when the earthquake intensifies do we see *all* of them running to the exit with chips, not cash. Rusty does call out to everyone around him to cash in but there's a stampede of people getting out, and not waiting to cash in. Since most of them didn't cash-in, Bank could easily change the chips the next day, causing the existing chips to be worthless, just like the movie 21.  So my question is; did Bank really lose 500 million that night?

Comment: I've heard on TV (and [this website](http://www.lasvegasadvisor.com/faq.cfm#9)) that you can cash casino chips at casinos other than the one you won them at, so people could exchange them at a non-earthquaking casino before they had time to invalidate them all.

Comment: Yes, to the tune of 500 million ? And even if you did do it in a span of a year, you would be cashing in 130 grand a day ! It would take around 4 years before every chip is cashed in without invoking notice from the casino bossess. That and the fact that every day some person would be cashing out 20 grand with the chips from the same casino

Answer (score 2):

I don't think people would have waited till next day to cash in the chips. There was big money at stake. Soon after the earth-quake had settled (which was only a few minutes), people would have went in to cash in the chips. 
Also, I don't think casinos can just change the chips without any reason.
There definitely was fraud and Willy Bank knew it but the problem is he can not prove it. So he is bound to pay everyone with their win.

Comment: "bound to pay everyone with their win" ?? Are you familiar with the workings of the casinos ? Aware who it's owners are ? What purpose it servers ?

Comment: Watch the movie 21, inspired by real life events portrayed in the book-Bringing Down the House, which is essentially all about the casino system and how it was bent to serve hand-full of people's purpose......until they were caught.

Comment: No I am not familiar with detailed working of casinos and who its owners are. All I am saying is that the folks who won did not do any fraud. Casino owners can sure deal with cheaters, but in this case the cheaters did not win anything, they made other people win. So other people think , they won it normally. If casino refuses to pay them, it will definitely earn them a bad name and no one would ever be returning again. Most importantly, Willy Bank can not prove there was a fraud. Not to anyone.

Comment: Well that's true. There was no proving that there was a fraud.